# What is the simplest way to write a text file in Java?

Tags: java, file, text

I am wondering what is the easiest (and simplest) way to write a text file in Java. Please be simple, because I am a beginner :D

I searched the web and found this code, but I understand 50% of it.

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class WriteToFileExample {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        String content = "This is the content to write into file";

        File file = new  File("C:/Users/Geroge/SkyDrive/Documents/inputFile.txt");

        // if file doesnt exists, then create it
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(content);
        bw.close();

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I think there is no easier code than this. Could you specify what you dont understand?

Comment: Thank you for your responce! Well I dont understand the what the FileWriter and BufferedWriter classes do. Oh and the carch(IOExeption) part at the end. Please can you explain me briefly what thay do.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

With Java 7 and up, a one liner using [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html):

```
String text = "Text to save to file";
Files.write(Paths.get("./fileName.txt"), text.getBytes());
```

Comment: That is simple, indeed! Thank you! :)

Comment: Probably should specify a charset.

Comment: @BradHards I agree but the question was for the simplest way and this is how simple it can be IMO.

Comment: Will this append to or overwrite the specified file?

Comment: The latter @Peri461

Comment: To append to the file, I think you can do `Files.write(myPath, myString.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND)` There's some other options you can use, too.

Comment: To specify a charset, could `Files.write(Paths.get("./fileName.txt"), text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));`

Answer (score 22):

You could do this by using `JAVA 7` new `File API`.

code sample:
`

```
public class FileWriter7 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<String> lines = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "This is the content to write into file" });
        String filepath = "C:/Users/Geroge/SkyDrive/Documents/inputFile.txt";
        writeSmallTextFile(lines, filepath);
    }

    private static void writeSmallTextFile(List<String> aLines, String aFileName) throws IOException {
        Path path = Paths.get(aFileName);
        Files.write(path, aLines, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Note that this is by far the simplest since all you really need is:  Files.write(file.toPath(), content.getBytes()); to meet the original question's goals.

Answer (score 21):

You can use [FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) from Apache Commons:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

final File file = new File("test.txt");
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, "your content", StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: If you have multiple lines, you can use `.writeLines()`.  And it closes everything for you properly in the case of exceptions, and no security issues with `System.getProperty`.  All this stuff is a pain without commons.

Answer (score 7):

Appending the file [FileWriter(String fileName,
          boolean append)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29)

```
try {   // this is for monitoring runtime Exception within the block 

        String content = "This is the content to write into file"; // content to write into the file

        File file = new  File("C:/Users/Geroge/SkyDrive/Documents/inputFile.txt"); // here file not created here

        // if file doesnt exists, then create it
        if (!file.exists()) {   // checks whether the file is Exist or not
            file.createNewFile();   // here if file not exist new file created 
        }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true); // creating fileWriter object with the file
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw); // creating bufferWriter which is used to write the content into the file
        bw.write(content); // write method is used to write the given content into the file
        bw.close(); // Closes the stream, flushing it first. Once the stream has been closed, further write() or flush() invocations will cause an IOException to be thrown. Closing a previously closed stream has no effect. 

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (IOException e) { // if any exception occurs it will catch
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the comments! Now the picture is more clear! :)

Comment: @BogGogo see the updated answer to append the file content without erase the previous content. FileWriter having the append file option. The default value of the attribute is false.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is the simplest. But, i always try to optimize the code further. Here is a sample.

```
try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("./output/output.txt")))) {
    bw.write("Hello, This is a test message");
    bw.close();
    }catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.toString());
    }
```

Comment: I don't think your FileWriter will be closed if you do it that way. Not sure if it matters though.

Answer (score 4):

Files.write() the simple solution as @Dilip Kumar said. I used to use that way untill I faced an issue, can not affect line separator (Unix/Windows) CR LF.

So now I use a Java 8 stream file writing way, what allows me to manipulate the content on the fly. :)

```
List<String> lines = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "line1", "line2" });

Path path = Paths.get(fullFileName);
try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(path)) {   
    writer.write(lines.stream()
                      .reduce((sum,currLine) ->  sum + "\n"  + currLine)
                      .get());
}
```

In this way, I can specify the line separator or I can do any kind of magic like TRIM, Uppercase, filtering etc.

Answer (score 3):

```
String content = "your content here";
Path path = Paths.get("/data/output.txt");
if(!Files.exists(path)){
    Files.createFile(path);
}
BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(path);
writer.write(content);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please not that code only answers may be deleted due to low qualitiy. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Additionally, please do not copy existing answers.

Answer (score 3):

In `Java 11` or Later, `writeString` can be used from `java.nio.file.Files`,

```
String content = "This is my content";
String fileName = "myFile.txt";
Files.writeString(Paths.get(fileName), content);
```

**With Options:**

```
Files.writeString(Paths.get(fileName), content, StandardOpenOption.CREATE)
```

More documentation about the [java.nio.file.Files](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html) and [StandardOpenOption](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html)

Answer (score -2):

```
File file = new File("path/file.name");
IOUtils.write("content", new FileOutputStream(file));
```

IOUtils also can be used to write/read files easily with java 8.